# Phonegap on Galaxy S3 ignores touch events

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events, samsung-mobile, galaxy

I am having a really odd issue.  I have a Phonegap 2.0 app that is basically completed.  It is working on iPhone and iPad and I ported it over to Android in a day, testing it on my Galaxy S.  Everything worked perfectly.  Then I tried to run it on my brand new S3 and none of the touch events worked.  Clicks work, but not touch.

If I run this code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) { console.log('touch start')}, false);
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) { console.log('doc click'); }, false);
```

... only the click events logs.  If I comment out the click I get nothing but the system clicks.

```
10-12 10:08:16.213: V/webview(2805): NO_FAST_DRAW = false
10-12 10:08:16.283: V/webview(2805):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE
```

The really weird thing is that the same touchstart works both on the S3 browser AND the PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin.  Just not in the webview portion of the app, and only on the S3.

[UPDATED]

And it gets weirder.  If I bind the event in the inline JavaScript code, such as this

```
// Javascript stuff
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) { alert('touch start')}, false);
// more JavaScript stuff
```

it actually works.  However, if I set it after a timeout it doesn't

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) { alert('touch start')}, false);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very sad to say, it looks like Ice Cream Sandwich does not support touch events (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390902/webview-in-ics-touch-events-not-being-fired-properly).  So iOS supports touch* events, Galaxy S supports touch* and mouse* and Ice Cream Sandwich (S3) does not support touch*.  Egads.  I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I've been successfully using touchstart, touchmove, etc. in PhoneGap apps for a while now on my Galaxy Nexus (ICS/JB). Perhaps this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10495741/710990.