# Error Exception: Already connected In java HttpURLConnection of post method

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am facing problem in this java function i am trying to post data from my table to server but not able to post as i am getting already connected error

Only the first record is posted

```
  public int myfuction(){

    try{

    String url = "myurl/page.php";
    String urlParameters=null;
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

      Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM temtable ", null);
      String id = null;
      if (c1 != null ) {
            if  (c1.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                suid = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("puid"));
                urlParameters ="text=STAT=1,DEVICEID=10,TERMINALID="+terminal+",USERID="+id;
               // Send post request
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                //con.disconnect();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Send Para-"+urlParameters, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pstatus = 1;
             }while (c1.moveToNext());
            }
            } 

      con.disconnect();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Send Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error:"+ ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return 1;
    }
```

This is what i am using please help...

Comment: When i click the button event get this

11-01 11:20:29.474: V/webview(26555): NO_FAST_DRAW = FALSE
11-01 11:20:29.544: V/webview(26555):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
11-01 11:20:32.804: D/dalvikvm(26555): GC_CONCURRENT freed 957K, 23% free 7272K/9415K, paused 3ms+4ms

Comment: @W-I-Z-A-R-D first "urlParameters" is posted and receiving on server...but for next it is showing alredy connected

Comment: Check this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12863814/2811956)

Comment: Then you need to close the connection after post

Comment: menace you are asking me to con.disconnect(); in while loop

Tried this but not working

Comment: Touch event is working

Comment: No don't close in while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `HttpURLConnection` via `URL.openConnection()` inside the loop, every time. You're trying to do connection pooling but `HttpURLConnection` already does that for you. When you finish with the last iteration, call `disconnect()` to provide the hint that this connection can be closed.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this snippet in while loop itself it work for me and disconnected every time

but this is bad practice to connect and disconnect every single request it loads the server with so many request

```
String url = "myurl/page.php";
String urlParameters=null;
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add reuqest header
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
```

so is there any another solution so that only once i can connect and post the data one by one on that connection

Comment: No it isn't bad practice, and I have already told you why. It certainly doesn't create any more requests than your original code.